# IOS Play Sound on receiving push notification when app in foreground

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

How to play sound on receiving a push notification when the app is in the foreground state.

My Code :

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
        //create an audio player and play the sound

        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"whistle" ofType:@"caf"];
        NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: path];
        AVAudioPlayer *theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:NULL];
        theAudio.volume = 1.0;
        [theAudio prepareToPlay];    
        [theAudio play];
    }

    NSLog(@"didReceiveRemoteNotification %@",userInfo);    
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instated of `AVPLayer`, you should try with following code:

Add following framework

```
#include <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
```

And use this code,

```
    SystemSoundID soundID;
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef ref = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef)@"mySoundName.wav", NULL, NULL);
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(ref, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

Comment: and `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);` to vibrate